# How to do EXISTS select in ANSI SQL

Tags: sql, ansi-sql

Is there a cross-database (at least SQL Server, Oracle, Postgre, MySQL, SQLite) way of doing what I would do in T-SQL using

```
SELECT 1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE Bar = 'Quux')
```

It seems that this is not valid ANSI SQL syntax because there is no FROM clause. At present I am using COUNT(*) to do this, but I don't think that's optimal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The subquery is unnecessary - use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       1 
  FROM Foo 
 WHERE Bar = 'Quux'
```

A more complicated version, using aggregates & CASE expression:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN COUNT(*) >= 1 THEN 1 
         ELSE 0
       END
  FROM Foo 
 WHERE Bar = 'Quux'
```

Comment: I wonder why not to use limit, instead of distinct? Isn't it ABSI compatible?

SELECT 
       1 
  FROM Foo 
 WHERE Bar = 'Quux' LIMIT 1;

Comment: @andrii Unfortunately, LIMIT is not ANSI compatible. As of SQL2008, we have the benefit of 'FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY' and windowed aggregate functions, but only a few database engines support them. Also LIMIT is quite different from DISTINCT. We know here all tuples we be the same, hence returning a single-row result with DISTINCT. No need to artificially interrupt the resultset here.

Answer (score 1):

Cheating a little, but this ought to work and the `DISTINCT 1 FROM Foo` should be trivially optimized by all but the dumbest of DBMSs!

`SELECT DISTINCT 1 FROM Foo WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE Bar = 'Quux')`

Answer (score 0):

Just use COUNT until you need otherwise. Assuming good selectivity on Bar and and index, it won't matter too much but will be far more readable

```
SELECT COUNT(Bar) FROM Foo WHERE Bar = 'Quux'
```

You will trade optimisation for portability of course, so in this case use COUNT

Comment: I'm working on a general purpose library, so I want the best mix of optimal and portable.

And a biscuit! :)